# Error when attempting to convert EventLoopFuture<Type> to Type

Tags: swift, event-loop, vapor

I'm new to coding in general and the concept of futures especially so patience would be appreciated! The goal of the following function is to check whether or not an account exists in a PostgreSQL database. If it does, return an empty UUID; if no account exists, create a new one and return its UUID. When I try to run my code, the error `Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<Account.idOut>' to return type 'Account.idOut'` appears next to the line `.map { Account.idOut(id: account.id!) }`. I've looked around here already and can't seem to find any solution to this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

```
func newAccount(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Account.idOut> {
        let input = try req.content.decode(Account.postAccount.self)
        
        //check to see if account already exists
        return Account.query(on: req.db)
            .filter(\.$email == input.email)
            .first().map { checkAccount in
                if checkAccount == nil {
                    let id = UUID()
                    let account = Account(id: id, fullName: input.fullName, email: input.email, password: input.password, type: input.type)
                    return account.save(on: req.db)
                        .map { Account.idOut(id: account.id!) }
                } else {
                    return Account.idOut(id: UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")!)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked in Vapor community chat.

Comment: @imike Sounds great. This might be a stupid request but could you please direct me to this community chat you speak of? Thanks :)

Comment: https://vapor.codes hit `Chat` button in the top right corner

Comment: @imike, chat is transient and only benefits the OP. Answering the question on SO creates a permanent resource and benefits all who encounter the same issue thereafter.

Comment: @Nick it is just basic knowledge of EventLoopFutures https://kirilltitov.com/en/blog/2019/futures

Answer (score 2):

In short, you need to return the same type to satisfy the compiler. This can definitely get a bit confusing with an `if`/`else` like yours where one returns a future and one doesn't. The way around it, is to return a future for both like so:

```swift
    func newAccount(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Account.idOut> {
        let input = try req.content.decode(Account.postAccount.self)
        
        //check to see if account already exists
        return Account.query(on: req.db)
            .filter(\.$email == input.email)
            .first().flatMap { checkAccount in
                if checkAccount == nil {
                    let id = UUID()
                    let account = Account(id: id, fullName: input.fullName, email: input.email, password: input.password, type: input.type)
                    return account.create(on: req.db)
                        .map { Account.idOut(id: account.id!) }
                } else {
                    return req.eventLoop.future(Account.idOut(id: UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")!))
                }
            }
    }
```

Important things to note:

- I changed the first `map` to a `flatMap` since you're returning a future inside
- I used `create` instead of `save` for the save operation as you're providing an ID and this forces Fluent to create the model. (Fluent will usually set the ID for you)
- I wrapped the account in `req.eventLoop.future` - this returns `EventLoopFuture<Account.idOut>` which satisfies the compiler